# How can I have a voltage in hall effect with zero magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

How can we obtain a voltage with no magnetic field is applied to the semiconductor?
They told me that if the points where I measure the potential difference are not at the same level I would obtain a voltage event if there is no magnetic field applied.

Comment: Sounds like a simple asymmetry in the geometry leading to an offset. You should be able to take that out of the measurement by averaging over two measurements with the magnetic field reversed.